# Same private methods to be used in one public method

Tags: java, android, private, public, main-activity

Please see the below code. I am creating a score keeping app and I have it set up to record certain stats for each team. So when I hit the + button for one team I want it to update that stat and then the same thing for the other team without it updating for the 1st team. I have also included a screenshot of the app itself (do please forgive the colouring for now lol). Is anyone able to provide any assistance, please? [Football Score Counter App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG2v0.jpg)

So basically: If I select the free kick option under the Home Team, I want it to update that and if the Away Team gets awarded a penalty, I want to be able to update that without updating for both teams at the same time. Or just update for one team. As that's what it's doing right now.

Android Studio tells me I cannot have "private void display(int number)" as it matches with the other one further down. So how do I differentiate them?

Many thanks and I hope I have done my best to explain it properly!

```
public void increment(View view) {
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    display(quantity);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount_text_view);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
```

I have edited this to also add part of the XML code that's being used:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrement_id"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/increment_id"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:text="+" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freeKick_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="FREE KICK"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrease_id"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/increase_id"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:text="+" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

So here, what I am saying is that FREE KICK needs to be updated for both teams but only when a free kick awarded to each team. So when I hit the + button for Home Team, they get the Free Kick. Then if the Away Team get a free kick, then hit the + button for them. Hope that makes thing clearer! :)

Comment: Usually you differentiate methods by giving them different names.

Comment: If it's the same code... why do you need to define it twice anywat? The whole point in having methods is that you can reuse them!

Comment: @niqueco It isn’t the same. `R.id.*` differs.

Comment: I’m no android expert but why not just name the methods differently?

Comment: Can you pass that as a parameter to the method?

Comment: Also I’m not sure if that’s your real address or not on your profile; but if it is, it’s probably not wise to have it publicly displayed.

Comment: @achAmháin Thanks for that! Didn't realise it was public!

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid duplicating similar functionality in two methods is to add an another parameter to the method signature:

```
/**
 * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number, @IntegerRes int viewId) {
    TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(viewId);
    quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
```

Then, you'd use the method as follows:

```
public void increment(View view) {
    quantity = quantity + 1;
    display(quantity, R.id.quantity_text_view);
    display(quantity, R.id.amount_text_view);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn’t want to update both views at the same time.

Comment: The above code works, but it is updating both views at the same time. I need it to update for each team individually, please. Thank you again for your assistance! :)

Comment: Then you need to call the `display()` method individually for each team. It's hard to give a suggestion without knowing the details of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate onClick methods for each increment and decrement buttons.

> ( onClick="DecrementQuantity" , onClick="IncrementQuantity" ,
>   onClick="DecrementFreeKick" , onClick="IncrementFreeKick" ,
>   onClick="DecrementAmount" , onClick="IncrementAmount" )

You should not use the same onClick method for more than one button. Each onClick manages an action for each textview.

```
public void DecrementQuantity(View v) {
        findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view).setText(Integer.toString(number));
    }
```

Comment: *Also, function names should start with a capital letter.* since when?!!!!

Comment: I have done something similar to this. Many thanks for your assistance. Now I just have to implement it to the rest of the app and it should all work fine!